# Is it possible to have smooth shading on only for rendering?

Tags: rendering, shaders

I'm tired of switching back and forth smooth shading for all my objects in the viewport before rendering. Is there a way to have it only turned on for rendering similar to the buttons in modifier for example?

Alternatively is there a way (possibly a script) with which I can set all meshes to smooth/flat with one button only?

Thank you!

Comment: imho not, but one (complicated) way would be to create a script that enables it, renders, then disables it... then you could create a custom button to render in that way,,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create an operator that will set the shading for all objects. This can be added to the render panel so you have buttons to set smooth and flat shading right above the render button. I have created an [addon here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sambler/addonsByMe/master/set_smooth.py) to do this, which you can [download and install](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/addons.html#header). If you enable the addon and click [Save User Settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/introduction.html#save-user-settings) you can have it enabled every time you run blender.

Keyboard shortcuts can also be setup for quick access, in the addon I setup <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> to set smooth shading and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> to set flat shading.

[image: render panel]

Comment: Wow this is pretty much what I asked for and seem to work, thank you very much!